# Delete cookies in IE11 F12 Developer Tools and Document Mode not Edge

Tags: internet-explorer, windows

I want to delete the cookies in IE10. I'm running IE11 on Win7 and have set the document mode in Emulation tab in F12 Developer Tools window to 10 (insted of default Edge).

My site sets some cookies with PHP. But when I try too delete the cookies in any way I could imagine, they are not gone.

I tried the Delete Cookies from Domain Button in Network Tab
I tried the Internet Options Delete Cookies method
I tried to remove the cookie with JavaScript.
The Cookies Folder in %USERDIR%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies\ is empty

None worked.

Comment: Have you tried [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner)?! What if you switch back to IE11 mode? If you monitor the HTTP requests do you see the `Cookie` header being sent?

Comment: Yes I did. To no avail